# get session id from warden or devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, warden

I need to grab the session id for a user and use it preferably in a model.

Here's the gist:

1) I have a list of proposals.
2) Unregistered users can create proposals and their session id is saved to them.
3) When a user registers or logs in their session id should be matched with proposals.
4) Then their user id should be saved to the proposal as well.

I've thought about overriding Devise controllers or using Warden hooks within the rails application file but these solutions seem messy.

Comment: No need to overide devise or warden here. Just get the `session.id` and use it on the records. When the user logs on you could display a flash message if they have records that are not saved to them. Then link to a controller action with the relinking logic.

Comment: Where is that available?

Comment: should be available when you set the session. Just try calling `<%= session.id %>` in a view or something.

Comment: I would like to access the session variable from the login and signup controller to simplify things since the user will land on the page where they were last.  I think you are suggesting that after a user logs in they should be sent to a specific page/controller?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following in controllers or views:

```
session['session_id']
=> '69384476b67fa4c2d1e3cc340eb4e951'
```

Comment: In some limited testing, it looks like session['session_id'] is reset upon successful login -- therefore the ID's are different.

Comment: it's reset to prevent [session fixation attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation)

Comment: It's empty variable